# SonarQube 4.3.2 Javascript exclude

Tags: sonarqube

We are using SonarQube version  4.3.2 with our Java project. We want to exclude all javascript files which are currently being analyzed. We tried excluding by using *.js in exclusion list, but it did not work.
Please help.

Answer (score 16):

In your `sonar-project.properties`, you have two ways to ignore files:

- `sonar.exclusions=the/full/path/*.xml` will ignore all `.xml` files in `path`.
- `sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml` will ignore all `.xml` files in the folder and sub-folders where you are.

Here are the different wildcards:

```
*    zero or more characters
**   zero or more directories
?    a single character
```

You can find more information on [Sonar Documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus)

Answer (score -3):

Following pattern will exclude all javascripts from Sonarcube analysis -

sonar.exclusions=**/*.js

Comment: This answer was already provided above, 2 years before you. This does nothing but add clutter.